# How to make a function that can return the box with information?

Tags: front-end, elided-forms

In the version 10, a lot of functions returned a box with brief information which is very useful.

For example:

```
Interpolation[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}]
```

[image]

So what's that little box, and how can I make a function that return a similar box which contains some of the information?

Comment: the little box is just a `Panel` with some info. I'll see if i can find a link to how to make them in your own functions. darren glosemeyer (formerly) at WRI wrote this up a few years ago.

Comment: and FWIW they are *terribly* annoying on the RPi, as it oftentimes takes longer to render the box than it does to run the underlying function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `MakeBoxes` to format output pretty much however you like.  This is what *Mathematica* does for `InterpolatingFunction`.  You may be able to glean something by inspecting the output cell or from `FormatValues[InterpolatingFunction]`.  Unlike `InterpolatingFunction`, I included an `Interpretation`, which means that the output in the notebook may be copied and used.  The `InterpolatingFunction` has a little `+` button that toggles between information panes.  I've included a `PaneSelector` and an `Opener` for that feature, in case you wanted that.  Just like `InterpolatingFunction`, this leaves little `Dynamic` bits littering your notebook.

Toy example:

```
MakeBoxes[myFN[n_], fmt_] := ToBoxes[
   Interpretation[
    Row[{
      HoldForm[myFN][
       DynamicModule[{open = False},
        Panel[Grid[{{
            Opener[Dynamic[open]],
            Graphics[{Green, Rectangle[]}, 
             ImageSize -> {Automatic, 
               Dynamic[
                3.5*(CurrentValue["FontCapHeight"]/
                   AbsoluteCurrentValue[Magnification])]}],
            PaneSelector[{
              False -> Row[{"Domain: ", Reals}],
              True -> Column[{Row[{"Domain: ", Reals}], 
                              Row[{"Formula: ", myFN[n][\[FormalX]]}]
                       }]},
             Dynamic[open],
             ImageSize -> Automatic (* pane resizes to current expression *)
             ]
            }}, Alignment -> {Left, Top}]] (* grid alignment *)
        ]]}],
    myFN[n]],  (* interpretation *)
   fmt];

makeFN[n_?NumericQ] := myFN[n];
myFN[n_?NumericQ][x_] := x^n
```

Usage:

```
f = makeFN[3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f[4]
(* 64 *)
```

With the `Opener` open:

```
makeFN[5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Copying the output from above and evaluating it at `2`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* 32 *)
```

Comment: related use of `Interpretation` http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29854/can-we-hide-mathematica-code/29882#29882

Answer (score 0):

The info on Mathgroup by Darren Glosemeyer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/AJZ1m6nbzkw) wasn't exactly what I remembered but if you change this line:

```
makeWrapper[data_List, var_Symbol, opts___] := myWrapper[data, var]
```

to

```
makeWrapper[data_List, var_Symbol, opts___] := myWrapper[Panel[data], var]
```

you can see how to include panels in your own functions:

[image]